# Read relations from file using igraph python

Tags: python, igraph

I have a `sample.txt` file containing this:

```
a b c
b d a h
a c
```

, where each line means there's a directed edge between each nodes, so the using the data above would do these relations:

```
a->b->c
b->d->a->h
a->c
```

Is there any way to import the file properly using python igraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
def iterpairs(iterable):
    prev = None
    for item in iterable:
        if prev is not None:
            yield prev, item
        prev = item

edges = []
for line in open("sample.txt", "r"):
    parts = line.strip().split()
    edges.extend(iterpairs(parts))

g = Graph.TupleList(edges)
```